# Laptop with Windows 7 turns on spontaneously while being in "Sleep" state

Tags: windows-7, laptop, sleep

I own a laptop(*HP Pavilion DV7*) with *Windows 7* installed for already half a year.
Usually when I finish my work I do not turn machine off - closing is enough to get is into "Sleep" state.

Generally it's okay for me, but recent several days laptop was turning on in night spontaneously, while I was sleeping.

- I haven't installed any app with "turn-on by schedule on
  when_dooes_pc_wants"-like features.
- Checked if there are some
  "Wake-On-Lan"-like settings in BIOS, haven't found ones.
- The power-cable is always plugged-in.

Does someone have any suggestions regarding that?

p.s. laptop is placed right near by bed, so when it turns-on on night - it is quite annoying and a bit scary. I think it's trolling me, please help to stop it :)

Thanks.

Comment: Alas, this is semi-normal for Windoze.  Though I haven't seen it as much with 7 as with Vista.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check device drivers in Device Manager, see if any are set to "allow this device to wake computer", disable them.

[image]

Comment: Found that "Allow device to wake the computer" flag was enabled for mouse; Probably it's sensitive enough to react on environment events(nearby subway, human steps, etc). Switched flag-off, think that helped. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hmmm, I don’t think this is the cause for mine (I’m fairly sure I already checked everything), but it certainly would explain why it turns on at *random* times. I’ll check it tomorrow to be certain. @alexb, thanks for specifying *which* device it was that caused it for you.

Comment: My computer has a whole lot of devices attached to it. I don't suppose there's a way to just auto magically get a list of all devices that have that checkbox checked?

Comment: @neubert: `powercfg.exe /devicequery wake_armed` at an Administrator command prompt.  `powercfg.exe /lastwake` is also useful

Answer (score 0):

In addition to moab's answer, you can usually find out which device was responsible for waking the computer as follows:

- Open a command prompt: Hit the windows key, type "cmd", and press enter.
- In the command prompt, type "powercfg /lastwake"

Using /lastwake is not perfect, but you can usually tell if it's an USB device or a network card that's waking the computer. If the device was woken up by one of the network cards, the issue is often that [Wake On LAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN) is enabled but not requiring a [magic packet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN#magic_packet).