# Win10 workstation randomly wakes up

Tags: windows-10, sleep, hibernate, wake-up, hybrid-sleep

I usually leave my workstation PC in sleep mode instead of shutting it down.
While often everything works as intended, sometimes the machine boots up without input (no wake on LAN, no key press). I could not link it to a time of the day or time elapsed since going into sleep mode yet, and it also does not happen every time. This also occurs if there is no update scheduled for Win10.

What I noticed though is that there is a difference between using the  button on [my keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yqD2.jpg) <sup>1</sup> ([source](https://shopotam.ru/catalog/Computers_Tablets_And_Networking/Keyboards_Mice_And_Pointing/Keyboards_And_Keypads/emachines/230849444350-item.html)) and the start menu option `Sleep Mode`: The PC will only load the BIOS with the latter, the former shows the login screen immediately. This tells me that those are two different states, but I do not know what else discerns them, or how to call them. As far as I know, the random wake ups only occur after using the  button.

Possibly relevant specs include:

```
OS:           Windows 10 Version 1709 (Build 16299.371)
CPU:          Intel i5-6600
Motherboard:  MSI Z170A SLI PLUS LGA1151
PSU:          EVGA SuperNOVA NEX 750W 80+
```

`powercfg /devicequery wake_armed` only shows the mouse, keyboard, and ethernet.
`powercfg /lastwake` only shows one entry, the power button.

What else I've tried so far:

- disabling "Allow this device to wake the computer" for all devices in the device manager, as per [Laptop with Windows 7 turns on spontaneously while being in “Sleep” state](https://superuser.com/questions/409275)
- disabling "Allow wake timers" in the energy settings as in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/983764) to [Windows 10 waking from sleep with unknown reason](https://superuser.com/questions/955262)
- unchecking "Wake the computer to run this task" on the UpdateOrchestrator Reboot service, again from [the answer mentioned before](https://superuser.com/a/983764). Confirming this change prompts me with an authentication window from Task Scheduler though, with the username `S-1-5-18` already filled in, which I do not know. Entering the correct admin user & pass will give the following error message (German):
  `Fehler für Aufgabe "Reboot". Fehlermeldung: Der folgende Fehler wurde gemeldet: Die angegebene formatfreie Struktur enthält ungültige Daten.`("*Error with task 'Reboot': Error: Error: the unformatted structure contains invalid data*"). All guides I found relating to this error message either say to disable "Allow wake timers", which I did, or do a clean reinstall of Win10, which I'd rather not.

## How do I stop my PC from waking up at random times during day and night?

---

<sup>1 <sub>upper right corner</sub></sup>

Comment: As far as I can tell in my experience with the very same problem, this is Update Orchestrator variables getting changed after an update happens. This is originally intended to allow windows to update again, but seems like it's returning the system elements to the original status.
You can tell because the fixes you tried tend to work for a few weeks and then stop.